# Use .htaccess to rewrite a subdomain to root with query string

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, query-string

Is it possible to use .htaccess to transparently rewrite a subdomain to show the content of the root domain while making the subdomain name available in the query string?

For example:

- https://sub.example.com/

transparently shows the content of:

- https://www.example.com/?sd=sub

Another example:

- https://sub.example.com/page.php?a=1&b=2

transparently shows the content of:

- https://www.example.com/page.php?a=1&b=2&sd=sub

I've tried multiple solutions and so far this is the closest I've gotten:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.example\.com?sd=%1 [QSA,L]
```

The only issue is that it redirects instead of rewriting.  As you can see, I am not using the [R] flag so I don't understand why it redirects unfortunately.  Also, I need to have the subdomain created in the hosting account for it to work...for example: https://test.example.com redirects to https://www.example.com?sd=test with the .htaccess above and that rewritten URL is shown to the visitor.  I also have to have the subdomain test.example.com created in the server for this to function.

Comment: Explanation for why this redirects: *If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL.* (from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). If you have sufficient access to the server to configure this then what you're trying to do is probably better achieved using `ServerAlias` with a wildcard.

Comment: Thanks, mikej...that sounds like the right way to go.  I was over-complicating it and the answer was much more simple: just create a new subdomain and point it's root to the site's root.  The subdomain can be programatically derived from the HTTP_HOST thereafter.